# flutter error when change min sdk to 18 and target sdk to 28

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to use SMS plugin, this plugin need min sdk 18 and target sdk 28, but when I change this I have this error :

```
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\64.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\72.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\73.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\86.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\88.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\89.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\90.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\91.jar, C:\Users\utilisateur\AndroidStudioProjects\nirbi_final_2\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\92.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I tried the android X migration ( refactor -> migrate to android X ) and add to the gradle.properties :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I tried

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

but nothing, always this error

Comment: Did you changed compileSdkVersion in build.gradle file to 28?

Comment: Yes, I found the problem, it's the package map_view who is no longer maintened, and is not compatible with android X